# Tablesort with EntityQuery

Tags: database

Inside a block plugin I'm creating a table (in Drupal8). Like so

```
            $header = [
                t('Name'),
                t('Number'),
                t('Rank'),
            ];
            $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
                ->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender')
                ->orderByHeader($header)
                ->condition('type', 'my_content_type')
                ->condition('status', 1)
                ->pager(5)
                ->execute();
            foreach ($nids as $nid) {
                $node            = \Drupal\node\Entity\NODE::load($nid);
                $row = [
                    'data' => [
                        $node->title->value,
                        $node->field_number->value,
                        $node->field_rank->value,
                    ],
                ];
                $rows[] = $row;
              }
            $render = [
                'table'           => [
                    '#prefix'        => '<h1>Entries</h1>',
                    '#theme'         => 'table',
                    '#attributes'    => [
                        'data-striping' => 0
                    ],
                    '#header' => $header,
                    '#rows'   => $rows,
                ],
            ];
            return $render;
```

Without the code below

```
 ->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender')
 ->orderByHeader($header)
```

the table renders just fine, but if I do include it I get the error

> Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Query::extend()

I'm guessing that it ->extend does not work on EntityQueries, but if that's the case how can I add table sorting to my table?

UPDATE: I've changed my $header array to include 'field' like so

```
            $header = [
                [
                    'data'  => t('Title'),
                    'field' => 'title'
                ],
                [
                    'data'  => t('Race'),
                    'field' => 'field_number'
                ],
                [
                    'data'  => t('Time'),
                    'field' => 'field_rank',
                ],
            ];
```

and tried adding

```
 ->tableSort($header)
```

to the query and removing extend and orderByHeader from the query but then I receive the following error

> Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryException: '' not found in
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\Sql\Tables->ensureEntityTable()

UPDATE 2:
I tried changing the $header array to use a specifier and type property like so.

```
                    'data'      => t('Name'),
                    'type'      => 'field',
                    'specifier' => [
                        'field'    => 'title',
                        'column'   => 'value',
                    ],
```

But I end up with the same error and get an additional error

> Undefined index: specifier in
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryBase->tableSort()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following some of the information found in Berdirs answer and comments I was able to arrive at a solution.

I formatted my header like so:

```
            $header = [
                'title'      => [
                    'data'      => t('title'),
                    'field'     => 'title',
                    'specifier' => 'title',
                ],
                'number'       => [
                    'data'      => t('Number'),
                    'field'     => 'field_number',
                    'specifier' => 'field_number',
                ],
                'time'       => [
                    'data'      => t('Time'),
                    'field'     => 'field_rank',
                    'specifier' => 'field_rank',
                ],
            ],
```

I then performed the EntityQuery like so

```
            $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
                ->tableSort($header)
                ->condition('type', 'my_content_type')
                ->condition('status', 1)
                ->pager($items_per_page)
                ->execute();
```

I formatted my rows like so

```
                $row = [
                    'data' => [
                        $node->title->value,
                        $node->field_number->value,
                        $node->field_rank->value,
                ];
```

After that generating the table was easy

```
            $render = [
                'table'           => [
                    '#prefix'        => '<h1>Entries</h1>',
                    '#theme'         => 'table',
                    '#attributes'    => [
                        'data-striping' => 0
                    ],
                    '#header' => $header,
                    '#rows'   => $rows,
                ],
            ];
```

The important parts I was missing is the proper format for $header. And using ->tableSort($header) instead of                 ->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender')
                ->orderByHeader($header) in my entityQuery

Answer (score 5):

<del>Entity query doesn't support extend() as you guessed and it also doesn't have any built in support for anything like Tablesort.</del>

You should still be able to define the $header (your example is not correct, it needs to have a key for the field at least and optionally default sort order) and then use tablesort_get_order() and tablesort_get_sort() to get the field to sort on as well as the sort direction.

Edit: Turns out entity query does support that with tableSort(), but as I said, your header definition is not correct, see comments.

Comment: Would tablesort_get_order() just be added as part of the query? Like ->condition('type','my_content_type')->tablesort_get_order($headers)->tablesort_get_sort($headers)?

Comment: Also I just found tableSort. Doesn't that take care of both of those? Either way I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Indeed, tableSort() seems to be basically this, wasn't aware this existed. This should definitely work if your header definition is correct, which your above example is not as I mentioned. See \Drupal\user\UserListBuilder::load and the buildHeader() method for a correct example